# Google Tango drift correction of ADF-localized pose

Tags: google-project-tango

I've got the [Area Learning C API example](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c/tree/master/cpp_area_description_example) running on my Google Tango but the pose after localization with respect to the ADF seems to be inaccurate: Below is an image of the outputted Tango position plotted alongside "ground truth" Tango position captured by motion capture sensors. I am supposing that this is because of accumulated drift, which is supposed to be minimal after localization.

[image]

The pose I am outputting is contained in the `adf_T_device_pose_` variable which is updated with the pose data returned by the `onPoseAvailable` callbacks in `area_learning_app.cc`.

Does this variable contain drift-corrected pose data as soon as it is updated?